# PL/SQL set exact length by random ora_hash

Tags: hash, plsql

I'm useing ora_hash to get a random hash which Looks like this.

```
SELECT ORA_HASH (userID || SYSTIMESTAMP || SYS_GUID ()) AS hash 
FROM DUAL;
```

The `userID` is a nNumber with 5 digits.
I've tested it a Long time and noticed that it generates me a number with a length between 7 and 10 digits.

Now I'd like to know if there is a good way to create a hash which always contains 10 Digits, means a number between 1000000000 and 9999999999.

Or should I take the differenct from the length to the number 10 and calculate it? What's the best way.

Comment: I believe that the max value which `ORA_HASH()` will produce is `4294967295`, which is ten digits, and less than `9999999999`.  See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions097.htm) here.

Comment: I see, '9999999999' was just a number to Show the range. My Goal is it to create a hash which contains always 10 digits.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done using the function alone.  It is possible to set a max, but the minimum is implicitly zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can anyways modify your query as well to get the 10 digit result. May be you can use as below:

```
select case when length(hash_val)> 10 then
           substr(hash_val,1,10)
           when length(hash_val) < 10 then
           lpad(hash_val,10,abs(dbms_random.random))
           else
           to_char(hash_val)
        end          
from (     
SELECT ORA_HASH ('00000' || SYSTIMESTAMP || SYS_GUID ()) AS hash_val 
FROM DUAL );
```

Comment: This Looks like what I've been searching. Just one Thing. since you've added dbms_random.random It generates me a negative number sometimes

Comment: I have added ABS as well will be always give positive result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1000000000+ORA_HASH (userID || SYSTIMESTAMP || SYS_GUID ()) AS hash
FROM DUAL;
```

should do the trick (won't go up to 9999999999, though, since ora_hash only goes up to 4294967295, so +1000000000 makes it 5294967295 at most)